# c# neo4jclient for filesystem representation - how to reduce high transaction count ? or optimize performance anyway?

Tags: c#, performance, neo4j, filesystems, neo4jclient

I'm trying to make a neo4j db representing my filesystem. Tried it with c# and neo4jclient but the process to read the filesystem and write to database is really slow in comparison to the same without sending transactions.

It recursively walks through my filesystem. For every folder a array with its subfolders is created and a cypher request with following method  (so breadth first traversing):

```
        public void createFolders(Folder[] folder, Folder rootFolder)
     {
         client.Cypher
            .Match("(root:FOLDER)")
            .Where((Folder root) => root.fullpath == rootFolder.fullpath)
            .Create("(folder:FOLDER {newFolders})")
            .CreateUnique("root -[:CONTAINS]->folder")
            .WithParam("newFolders", folder)
            .ExecuteWithoutResults();

     }
```

Any hints for more performance?
Is it better to make bigger arrays to create ? Or does neo4jclient do requests for each folder in folder[] anyway?

**edit:**
After some analysis with wireshark, I can see that `Cyper.Create()` with an array as parameter, does create one request to the database server with a parameter array including all subfolders.

I don't know how to go deeper to analyse the performance, sometimes the script creates `6000 nodes/min`  sometimes only *50 nodes/min*.

If my C# folder traversing runs without the `Cypher.ExecuteWithoutResults()` the script is much faster.

So any ideas to analyse or improve the performance?

*Sorry, It's my first Stackoverflow question so please give hints to imporve the question.*

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to do, but wouldn't you want to create one node per folder?

Then you need a foreach around your folder list.

You could also collect all parent->child pairs from your fs and send them in as a long list param and then use `foreach` over them.

Or generate a CSV and use LOAD CSV.

Comment: The method above creates one node per folder because a Folder[] is taken as input. The structue of the tree is exactly what I want (exactly the filesystem structure) , but the performance is not good enough, I think there are too many transactions or requests or something.